# How to select anchors by mime attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a group of some number of tags like these:

```
<a href="attachment/72" mime="image" target="_blank" class="value attachment">Filename.jpg</a>

<a href="attachment/73" mime="archive" target="_blank" class="value attachment">Filename.zip</a>
```

Is it possible to select with jQuery only anchors with attribute "mime" set to "image"?

Comment: Yes, have you even looked at the [API](http://api.jQuery.com/), tried anything at all? Hint: [attribut-equals selector](http://api.jQuery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Yes I have. I always thought that in selectors with [name="value"] name refers to the attribute "name", not an attribute's name. That's because such selectors are often used to select inputs by their name in form processing.

Comment: Well, 'it', in your example, *does* refer to the attribute `name`, which *is* also the attribute's/property's name. Unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yepp, it does. But the example isn't mine; it's from jQuery API page. I just thought that either 'name' is the only possible value, or there is only a limited set of allowed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('a[mime=image]');
```

Answer (score 0):

use Attribute selector in jquery like this

```
$("a[mime=image]").attr("href" , "image.png");
```

or if you want only archive attribute means

```
 $("a[mime=archive]").attr("id" , "someId");
```